# Почему этот радиальный градиент не завершает круг?

Tags: css, css3, html5, градиент

Я пытаюсь использовать радиальный градиент для создания границы внутри элементов круга, которые выполняют роль радио кнопок.

Основной CSS показан ниже. Я не могу понять, почему красный градиент не охватывает всю окружность.
Когда белый `color-stop` приближается к 100%,  появляются красные пробелы  сверху, справа, слева и снизу.

Почему это происходит, и как  это исправить,  используя радиальный градиент?

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.radio1 { background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 75%, red 100%); }
.radio2 { background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 90%, red 100%); }
.radio3 { background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 95%, red 100%); }
.radio4 { background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 99%, red 100%); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
  <div class="radio radio1"></div>
  <div class="radio radio2"></div>
  <div class="radio radio3"></div>
  <div class="radio radio4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56399252/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В соседнем ответе поднимается и подробно объясняется довольно интересная, но... специфическая ситуация. Ответ же может быть короче, если затрагивать только суть проблемы и нацелиться на конечный результат.

Вам нужен круг? У круга два основных параметра: координаты центра и радиус. По умолчанию координаты равны *at center* (или *at 50% 50%*), поэтому можно опустить этот параметр. Вы же смещаете центр к границе элемента, используя *closest-side*.

Следующий параметр - радиус. Снова, обратимся к значению по умолчанию - форма градиента (если не указана) - *ellipses*. Но, так как *width = height* - получаем квадрат, а с помощью *border-radius = 50%* - круг. Так что можно этот параметр тоже не указывать.

Также у `<div>` отсутствует *border*, если он явно не указан - это избавляет нас от коррекции *background-origin*.

Про использование *calc()* уже написали - на крупных объектах от процентной записи будет заметен эффект, но на мелких элементах без использования *calc()* не обойтись.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px; width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px; width: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(white calc(100% - 6px), red calc(100% - 5px));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Как отмечено в комментариях, ваш процент будет пересчитан в пикселях относительно вашей ширины / высоты. В вашем случае, 99% и 100% будут очень близки, и у вас возникнет проблема с воспроизведением субпикселей.

Вместо этого вы можете использовать `calc()`, где вы можете легко определить толщину в виде значения в пикселях независимо от размера элемента.

Вам также необходимо настроить `background-origin` и сделать его `border-box`, чтобы вы рисовали градиент с учетом области границы, и у вас получился идеальный круг.

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-origin:border-box;
}

.radio1 { background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 1px), red 100%); }
.radio2 { background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 2px), red 100%); }
.radio3 { background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 3px), red 100%); }
.radio4 { background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
  <div class="radio radio1"></div>
  <div class="radio radio2"></div>
  <div class="radio radio3"></div>
  <div class="radio radio4"></div>
</div>
```

Вот еще один пример с большим значением `border`, чтобы лучше проиллюстрировать проблему `background-origin`:

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio radio4"></div>
</div>
```

Фон рисуется на `padding box`, затем повторяется по всей области (`border box`).

Если вы отключите повтор, то у вас будет это:

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
</div>
```

Здесь мы повторим только на оси X:

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); 
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
</div>
```

И вот что происходит при использовании 100% для обоих цветов, что похоже на вашу ситуацию, и вы лучше поймете, почему у вас есть окраска только на углах.

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white 100%, red 100%); 
 }
 
 .one {
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
 }
  .two {
   background-repeat:repeat;
 }
 .three {
   border-width:5px;
```

```html
 }
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio one"></div>
  <div class="radio two"></div>
  <div class="radio three"></div>
</div>
```

И если мы изменим `origin`, это нормально:

```css
.container {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
 background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, white calc(100% - 4px), red 100%); 
  background-origin:border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="radio"></div>
</div>
```